# Float placement for lstnewenvironment

Tags: floats, listings

I've defined this environment:

```
\lstnewenvironment{pddl3}[1][]
{
    \lstset{
        keywordstyle=\color{black},
        commentstyle=\color{black},
        language= VBScript, 
        basicstyle=\small,
        numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,
        stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt, frame=shadowbox, float=*, #1
    }
}{}
```

And i can't find a way to force the listing that i put in the document to stay under some text. For example i try this way but it does not change anything:

```
\begin{pddl3}[caption=Esempio di azione STRIPS,float,floatplacement=H]\label{l_strips}]
(:action sposta
:parameters (?v ?f ?t)
:precondition (and (at ?v ?f) (diverso ?t ?f))
:effect (and (at ?v ?t) (not (at ?v ?f))
)
\end{pddl3}
```

Comment: Please provide a title for your question that is a bit more specific: problem with X is just too general. E.g. it would help if you could state the reason of your concern, which appears to be related to float placement. For what is worth, (I may be wrong) it seems to me you are not familiar with LaTeX's float placement, which may result in floats ending up _before_ or _after_ the place where you define the floats.

Comment: No problem. I think the current title is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you specify the `float` option if you don’t want the listing to float at all?  You can have a `caption` option and a `label` option (beware: *not* `\label`) even without creating a floating object.  Try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color} % or xcolor
\usepackage{listings}
\addto\captionsitalian{%
    \def\lstlistingname{Codice}%
}

\lstnewenvironment{pddl3}[1][]
{
    \lstset{
        keywordstyle=\color{red}, % just to check that it works
        commentstyle=\color{black},
        language= VBScript, 
        basicstyle=\small,
        numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,
        stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt, frame=shadowbox, #1
    }
}{}

\begin{document}

Testo che precede il listato.

\begin{pddl3}[caption={Esempio di azione STRIPS},label=l_strips]
(:action sposta
:parameters (?v ?f ?t)
:precondition (and (at ?v ?f) (diverso ?t ?f))
:effect (and (at ?v ?t) (not (at ?v ?f))
)
\end{pddl3}

Testo che segue il codice~\ref{l_strips}.

\end{document}
```

(Adapt the code to your needs, this is just an example.)  Here is what you get:

[image: Output of the code]